# How to two network interface same project diffrent controllers in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to use two network interfaces to expose two controllers in a same project in java spring?

By example: use Spring Cloud for route internal apis and same time serve a internal route for administration, but for security reason need expose the api route on `eth0` network interface and admin paths on `ethManage` interface.

Is it possible in Java Spring?

Comment: You would need explicit configuration and setup for that.